# Workings on +% damage, elemental vs physical

Tags: grim-dawn

Some weapons have +% physical damage, but it seems that this does not show up on the stats. Does it still multiply with full weapon damage? Because there are many +% damage stats, like +10% fire damage, but it seems to me that only increases the fire damage you already have. So if you have no fire damage it does nothing. I have a weapon that has +29% physical damage, is that really a full 29% increase? It doesn't show on the stats.﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've guessed correctly, +% damage simply increases the damage you already have. Now depending on your class it's very possible that you have indeed little to no Physical damage that gets increased by your items.

Now physical damage is mostly used by classes that wield Melee or ranged weapons. magic weapons (Daggers, Wands) usually have an element assigned to them, removing any physical damage you'd normally gain from a normal weapon attack.

While it's certainly possible to have zero physical damage, chances are that you will gain some at least on your main weapon attack (unless you're a full caster). **[Here](http://grimdawn.wikia.com/wiki/Physical_Damage)** is a list of spells that adds, removes or modifies physical damage.

For the part about it not showing: You can always see how +% physical damage modifies your current dps. If you hover the Damage per Second display in your character menu you'll see how much damage your (main) spells deal and also your normal auto attack. A +30% increase will simply add 30% more physical damage to your auto attacks and spells/auras and it's very possible and on some classes even viable to go higher than that.